# ¿Cómo obtener una lista de ventanas (carpetas o directorios) abiertos desde C#?

Tags: c#

Estoy intentando obtener una lista de carpetas abiertas (las que aparecen en la barra de tareas) desde C#, he intentado un código y no muestra nada. Por ejemplo en la lista obtener el titulo de las ventanas.

```
private void cargarLista()
{   
     System.Diagnostics.Process[] processes = 
     System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("explorer");
     foreach (System.Diagnostics.Process p in processes)
     {
         listBox1.Items.Add(p.MainWindowTitle);
     }  
}
```

Quiero una lista de las ventanas (el titulo) abiertas. Estoy Visual Studio Windows Form.

tal vez sea el nombre del proceso y no tengo idea que proceso es para listar los nombre de carpetas abiertas.

Comment: Y lo probaste? estas seguro que el proceso se llama explorer? que quiere decir que no muestra nada? que hace esto? tira un error? te fijaste que procesos tenias abiertos?

Comment: No muestras si estas cargando el ArrayList en un control, por lo tanto, ese debe ser tu error.

Comment: "que quiere decir que no muestra nada?" Quiero decir que no, carga en un listbox los nombres de carpetas abiertas. Ahora el nombre del proceso podria ser y no se cual pueda ser.

Comment: He modificado la pregunta en el código.

Comment: Probaste hacer un debug proceso por proceso a ver que procesos realmente tenes? no solo los explorer? cuando abro una carpeta en win 10 figura como explorador de archivos. el nombre puede ser cualquier cosa...

Comment: El título del post es confuso. No será 'como obtener una lista de procesos (o de ventanas) abiertos? Pero no de carpetas